# End up loop once the next document starts (Python 3)

Tags: json, regex, python-3.x, loops

I will like to end a loop once the next entry starts. For example, imagine I have the following txt file composed by three documents:

```
Document 1
text1
text1
tex1
Document 2
text2
text2
text2    
Document 3
text3
text3
text3
```

I am trying to build a `JSON` file that concatenates each text from a single article. e.g `'body' = text1 text1 text1`; `'body' = text2 text2 text2`; and `'body' = text2 text2 text2`. To do so, I search for the word `Document` and then basically concatenate the text that follows it in a single line. The problem is that my code skips one document so it only work for Document 1 and 3:

```
for line in f:
    if re.search(r"Document ", line):
        text = ''
        while not re.search(r"Document ", line):
            text += line+' '                     
        article['body'] = text
```

Any idea on how can I tell the code to stop (`while not`) once a next document starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following Python code:

```
article = []
start_matching = False
text = ""
with open(path, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if re.match(r"Document\s+\d", line):
            start_matching = True
            if text:
                article.append(text.strip())
                text = ""
            text += line
        else:
            if start_matching:
                text += line
if text:
    article.append(text.strip())

print(article)
# => ['Document 1\ntext1\ntext1\ntex1', 'Document 2\ntext2\ntext2\ntext2', 'Document 3\ntext3\ntext3\ntext3']
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/NMQ83244).

The point is that matching only starts when a line starts with `Document`, 1+ whitespaces and then a digit (`if re.match(r"Document\s+\d", line):`), then lines belonging to that document are added and then appended to the list (you may adjust the output for your needs).

Answer (score 1):

If we are using a regex and we can do it all in a regex then let the regex do the the hard work:

```
>>> regex = r"Document\s+\d+((?:(?!\s*Document\s+\d+)\s*.*)+)"
>>> re.findall(regex, str)
```

Outputs

```
['text1\ntext1\ntex1', 'text2\ntext2\ntext2', 'text3\ntext3\ntext3']
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/xZSX53/1)

Regex breakdown:

- `Document\s+\d+` Match a delimiter string
- `(` Start of capturing group #1

  - `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

    - `(?!\s*Document\s+\d+)` If we are not reaching next delimiter
    - `\s*.*` Match current line
  - `)+` End of non-capturing group, repeat as much as possible
- `)` End of capturing group #1